# Python filter nested Dict

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I am a beginner to python and am trying to figure out how to filter a dict in the best way possible. I have read several different ways to do this, but none in the exact way I want it. I have the below dict:

```
{
    "clients": [{
        "name": "John A",
        "Age": "27",
        "data": {
            "gender": "Male",
            "height": "6'2"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "John B",
            "age": "31",
            "data": {
                "gender": "Male",
                "height": "5'11",
                "telephones": [{
                    "home": "1234567890"
                },
                {
                    "mobile": "0987654321"
                }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

This can contain a lot of other data and clients. So what I am trying to do is filter the dict so I only retrieve the fields I want and put it in a new dict. For example, I am requesting the name, gender, and home phone of all clients. I loop through all the clients and have been trying to use the below code but I cant get the nested fields to work. Is there any way to use "in" to filter nested fields? Thanks

```
new_dict = {
    key: v for k, v in clientDict.items() 
        if k in {'name'}
        #I've tried 'data.gender' or anything I've tried doesn't work here
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have a nested dictionary, your filtering logic also has to be nested.  Here's an example that works with the sample data you've provided and returns the filtered data in its original structure:

```
new_dict = {
    "clients": [{
        "name": client["name"],
        "data": {
            "gender": client["data"]["gender"],
            "telephones": [
                phone
                for phone in client["data"].get("telephones", [])
                if "home" in phone
            ]
        }
    } for client in client_dict["clients"]]
}
```

If you wanted to do it without hardcoding the specific structure, a recursive function is a good way to handle arbitrary nesting.  Here's an example with a function that takes a set of keys to include; this produces a slightly nicer result than the hard-coded version because it can filter out the empty `telephones` list if there's no home phone given:

```
def filter_nested_dict(obj, keys):
    if isinstance(obj, list):
        new_list = []
        for i in obj:
            new_i = filter_nested_dict(i, keys)
            if new_i:
                new_list.append(new_i)
        return new_list
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        new_dict = {}
        for k, v in obj.items():
            if k not in keys:
                continue
            new_v = filter_nested_dict(v, keys)
            if new_v:
                new_dict[k] = new_v
        return new_dict
    return obj

new_dict = filter_nested_dict(
    client_dict,
    {"clients", "name", "data", "gender", "telephones", "home"}
)

from pprint import pprint
pprint(new_dict)
```

Result:

```
{'clients': [{'data': {'gender': 'Male'}, 'name': 'John A'},
             {'data': {'gender': 'Male',
                       'telephones': [{'home': '1234567890'}]},
              'name': 'John B'}]}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works almost perfect. The only issue is if the keys passed in match multiple values, it can return incorrect data. For example, if the initial dict contained a driversLicense(number,state,country,etc) and address(country,state,zipcode,etc). If i requested {"driverLicense","country", "address", "state"}, I would get the driverLicense state back even if I only wanted the address state. Is there a way to do this where Im passing in multiple sets of keys like {"driverLicense,"country"},{"address","state"}? Ive tried a for loop and combining the dicts but that doesnt seem to work well

Comment: Instead of passing in a set of all the keys, pass them in as structured data, and descend the key hierarchy as you recurse.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like:

```
clients = []
for elem in data['clients']:
    clients.append({k: v for k, v in elem.items() if k in {'name', 'gender'}})
print({'clients': clients})
```

**Output:**

```
{'clients': [{'name': 'John A'}, {'name': 'John B'}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, little bit more explicit. It will create new list with clients with key `home_phone` where values are lists with home phone numbers:

```py
dct = {
    "clients": [
        {
            "name": "John A",
            "Age": "27",
            "data": {"gender": "Male", "height": "6'2"},
        },
        {
            "name": "John B",
            "age": "31",
            "data": {
                "gender": "Male",
                "height": "5'11",
                "telephones": [
                    {"home": "1234567890"},
                    {"mobile": "0987654321"},
                ],
            },
        },
    ]
}


def get_all_home_phones(lst):
    out = []
    for phone in lst:
        if "home" in phone:
            out.append(phone["home"])
    return out


out = []
for c in dct["clients"]:
    out.append(
        {
            "name": c["name"],
            "gender": c["data"]["gender"],
            "home_phone": get_all_home_phones(c["data"].get("telephones", [])),
        }
    )

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[
    {"name": "John A", "gender": "Male", "home_phone": []},
    {"name": "John B", "gender": "Male", "home_phone": ["1234567890"]},
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution can solve your task. `item.get()` is like a parity check, it will return `None` if `name` is not present. Similarly it will check first `if 'data' in item`, if it does not find `data` attribute it will bypass the remaining block.
Thus, following code will run whatever the condition becomes, it will run and show results as you want.

```
clients = {}
details = []
for item in data['clients']:
    clients['name'] = item.get('name')
    clients['age'] = item.get('age')

    if 'data' in item:
        if 'gender' in item['data']:
            clients['gender'] = item['data']['gender']
        
        if 'telephones' in item['data']:
            for contact in item['data']['telephones']:
                if 'home' in contact:
                    clients['telephones'] = [contact.get('home')]

    details.append(clients.copy())
```

Prints:

```
[{'name': 'John A', 'age': '27', 'gender': 'Male'}, 
 {'name': 'John B', 'age': '31', 'gender': 'Male', 'telephones': ['1234567890']}]
```